# Timing in a python thread to execute two separate tasks

Tags: python, multithreading, time, milliseconds

I have a Python thread which opens a connection to a serial port using pyserial. In this thread, I'd like to write to the serial port only once every 30 milliseconds, but read from the port as fast as possible.

My idea was in the thread's run method to check if 30 milliseconds had elapsed with time.time(), and if not, to skip the write and move on to the read.

When I run the stripped down example below, the code inside that if block is runs every 2 ms or so (I would expect every 30 ms), which leads me to believe time.time() might not be reliable enough to be used this way, might not work properly inside a thread, or I'm making a silly mistake. I'm on OSX, Python 2.7

```
import threading
import time

class TestThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.daemon = True

        self.last_time = 0
        self.next_update = 0
        self.current_time_ms = 0
        self.update_rate = 30

        self.alive = threading.Event()
        self.alive.set()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive.isSet():
            self.current_time_ms = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
            if self.current_time_ms >= self.next_update:

                # WRITE TO SERIAL PORT EVERY 30 MS

                print self.current_time_ms - self.last_time
                self.last_time = self.current_time_ms

        # READ FROM SERIAL PORT AS FAST AS POSSIBLE

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "main"

    aThread = TestThread()
    aThread.start()

    while True:
        # Do nothing overe here
        pass
```

Comment: next_update is 0. the if will always return true.

Comment: Take a look at `threading.Timer` which allows you to pass a callback function to be executed after a period of time has passed. Your callback can also schedule andother Timer object so it is run every 30 seconds.